# How to download an HTML string using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, fetch-api

Is there any way to download an HTML string (code of a given web page) using JavaScript (despite CORS)? Something like:

```js
let url = "http://example.com";
fetch(url).then(a => document.write(a)).catch(a => document.write("Error"));
```

Comment: possibly not. https://stackoverflow.com/q/45880117/212869